# Add data into table with many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I just need to create a new Article with many to many relationship for tags. I have 3 tables:

```
 public class Article
{        
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeroImage { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }


    public virtual List<ArticleTag> ArticlesTags { get; set; }
    public Article()
    {
        ArticlesTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ArticleTag> ArticlesTags { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        ArticlesTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
 public IActionResult CreateNewArticle()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewArticle(ArticlesView av)
    {


        Article artical = new Article { Name = av.Name, Category = av.Category,
            ShortDescription =av.ShortDescription, Description=av.Description, Date = av.Date };


           // some code to add Tags from View


        db.Add(artical);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("AdminView");
```

My Model for creation:

```
public class ArticlesView
{
    public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public string Category { get; set; } 
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

}

And View:

```
<form asp-action="CreateNewArticle" asp-controller="home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">The name of article</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ShortDescription" class="control-label">Short description</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="ShortDescription" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label">Description</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label">Category</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Category" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label">Date of creation</label>
    <input type="date" asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

As I get it right I just need to add data to my 3rd table ArticleTag (ArticleId, TagId columns), but I don't understand what type of data should be inputed in View's fields and what I should do in my Controller. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new `Article` and add the existing tags to the article, and save the relationship to the database table `ArticleTag`, you could refer to the following :

1. Add `List<int> Tags` to save the id of choosed tags in ArticlesVM

   ```
   public class ArticlesVM
   {
     public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Category { get; set; }
     public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     public List<int> Tags { get; set; }
   }
   ```

2.Get the existing tags and then show them in select tag helper

```
public IActionResult CreateNewArticle()
    {
        ViewBag.Tags = new SelectList( _context.Tags.ToList(),"Id","Name");
        return View();
    }

@model EFCoreManyToMany.Models.ArticlesVM

<form asp-action="CreateNewArticle" asp-controller="home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">The name of article</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ShortDescription" class="control-label">Short description</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="ShortDescription" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label">Description</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label">Category</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Category" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label">Date of creation</label>
    <input type="date" asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Tags" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Tags" asp-items="@ViewBag.Tags" multiple></select>
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

3.Save data to the database

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewArticle(ArticlesVM av)
    {
        Article artical = new Article
        {
            Name = av.Name,
            Category = av.Category,
            ShortDescription = av.ShortDescription,
            Description = av.Description,
            Date = av.Date

        };
       _context.Add(artical);

        foreach(var tagId in av.Tags)
        {
            var tag = _context.Tags.Find(tagId);
            ArticleTag articleTag = new ArticleTag { Article = artical, Tag = tag };
            _context.Add(articleTag);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("AdminView");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it works almost perfecrly. But this way I can add only one tag whilst I need to have the ability to add many

Comment: The demo can add many tags for one article , see the[`multiple`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) attribute that  allows multiple selections in `select` tag helper.